# Getting error message in SqlDataAdapter.Update()

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable, sqldataadapter, sqlparameter

I have a DB table (which is empty in this example)

```
create table words
(
    id int not null,
    word nvarchar(50) not null
)
```

and a `DataGridView` which I'm filling like that:

```
    private SqlConnection _conn;
    private SqlDataAdapter _wordsAdapter;
    private DataTable _wordsDataTable = new DataTable();
    private DataGridView _tblWords;

    private void FillWords()
    {
        _wordsAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(new SqlCommand("select id, word from words", _conn));
        _wordsAdapter.Fill(_wordsDataTable);

        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "id";
        column.Name = "id";
        _tblWords.Columns.Add(column);

        column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        column.DataPropertyName = "word";
        column.Name = "word";
        _tblWords.Columns.Add(column);

        _tblWords.DataSource = _wordsDataTable;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _wordsAdapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("insert into words (id, word) values (@id, @word)", _conn);
        SqlParameter p = _wordsAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
        p.SourceColumn = "id";
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
        p = _wordsAdapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@word", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
        p.SourceColumn = "word";
        p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
        _wordsAdapter.Update(_wordsDataTable);
    }
```

Then I fill a single row of _**tblWords** with some values and call `Update()`. And get this message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' in
>   System.Data.dll 
>   *Additional information: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'DB.MDF.dbo.words'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.*

Why the value for 'id' is not taken from DataTable? What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
After inserting this code in the beginning of Update() function, everything works fine:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        _wordsDataTable.Rows.Clear();
        _wordsDataTable.Rows.Add(0, "xxx");
        ...
```

So the problem only appears when I fill the DataTable through DataGridView. Why?!

Comment: You are taking data from the datagridview and inserting it into the table. ID column should be primary key or identity column and hence it is not allowing you to insert a duplicate value. If you want to update the word column in the table, then use UPDATE statement.

Comment: The table is empty, so the row is INSERTED in this particular case. There are no duplicates because the row inserted is the first row in the table. But I still get the error.

Comment: I'm trying to get your code to run.What is `_cb`?

Comment: I'm sorry, actually _cb is not necessary in this example. Changed it for 'new SqlCommand()'

Comment: Have you looked at this in the debugger and checked that you have values in the data table?

Comment: Yes, I have values. Actually DataRow is absolutely identical when I add it through DataGridView and when I add it like this _wordsDataTable.Rows.Add(0, "xxx");

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem is related to the last empty row in the DataGridView.

You can try something like this instead of the last `_wordsAdapter.Update(_wordsDataTable);` line

```
var haveDbNull = _wordsDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToLookup(r => r.ItemArray.Contains(DBNull.Value));

Debug.Print("have DbNull values: " + haveDbNull[true].Count()); // check this number in the Debug Output window
Debug.Print("don't have DbNull values: " + haveDbNull[false].Count()); 

_wordsAdapter.Update(haveDbNull[false].ToArray());  // to update just the rows that dont have DBNull values
```

Comment: The row that is inserted has no null values. That's the problem. When I insert it value by value through DataGridView, I get the error. When I insert it to DataTable programmatically, everything is all right.

Comment: I am not sure why you use `p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;`. You should remove those or change them to `p.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Current;` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowversion

Comment: I tried Current as well, with the same result. If I remove it at all, there will be another error, saying that the parameter value is not supplied. The problem is that it takes null value instead of the current value from DataTable.

Comment: then I give up .. You can try with the sample at http://csharp.net-informations.com/dataadapter/datagridview-sqlserver.htm and go from there

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution. I just remove the added row and add the same values programmatically.

```
    object[] rowValues = dt.Rows[row].ItemArray;
    dt.Rows.RemoveAt(row);
    dt.Rows.Add(rowValues);
```

Does anyone know any less ugly way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple as always...

```
    _dtWords.EndInit();
```